# Can not migrate Android project . Problem Is Card.IO

Tags: java, android, androidx, card.io

I try to migrate my old project to Android X. I searched about it and migrated successfully.
I have one problem.In my project,I'm using Card.io. I downloaded and imported into the project from here

```
https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-source
```

When I try to run my app ,I have this error message

[image]

I searched much ,but still can't solve this problem. Unfortunately,I can't open new issue in Github repository, because repository has only read status.

Can anyone explain ,how I can solve this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We converted to AndroidX a large project and use Card.io.
We have
implementation 'io.card:android-sdk:5.5.1'
in the build.gradle and have no issues.
Are you trying to use the source? If you are and don't customize the source, the library implementation should be the best usage.